# What is the advantage of having typed interface over method that receives a certain type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, types, interface

I'm writing a class in Java and I want to implement `Comparable` interface. This is the class:

```
public class Flight implements Comparable {
    private int flightTime;
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Flight f = (Flight) o;
        return this.flightTime - f.flightTime;
    }
}
```

Now I learned that we can also add type to the interface as follows:

```
public class Flight implements Comparable<Flight> {
    private int flightTime;
    public int compareTo(Flight f) {
        return this.flightTime - f.flightTime;
    }
}
```

What are the advantages of the second implementation (please do not reduce the question to the advantages of generics in general)?

I'm fairly new to Java and I suspect that there must be some upside to adding the type, because on the face of it the implementations achieve the same goal. Also it looks like the implementation of `compareTo(Object o)` may be giving us more information because we could be testing for `instanceof` and potentially handling errors.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html lists out certain **Benefits of using generics** and most of those cases could be applied to different use cases in your above approaches.

Comment: Also don't you think its too broad to discuss the benefits of using one approach over the other?

Comment: @nullpointer as I mentioned I'm fairly new to Java so I wouldn't know what is too broad and what isn't

Comment: "we can also add" you *should always* add. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your first code, you will get an exception at run time if you do something like this:

```
int i = new Flight().compareTo("xyz");
```

With your second code, you will get a compile-time error if you try to do that.

Sorry, but that's the basic advantage of generics in general and it applies to the particular case you posted. Generics simply move a lot of run-time errors to compile time. Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), they don't really do much more than that.

Comment: I could avoid the run-time error in the first example if I tested for `o instanceof Flight` though right?

Comment: @Yos - Absolutely. But that introduces an `instanceof` test (complicating your implementation) and what would you do if the `instanceof` test failed? The method has to either return some `int` value or throw an exception. If the former, then you're allowing calling code to compare instances of `Flight` to anything at all (thus generating apparently meaningful results for nonsense input) and if the latter, then the calling code has to deal with possible exceptions, complicating that code as well. (Plus, you then haven't avoided a run-time error.)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you're doing yourself at runtime what the compiler can do for you at compile time (the second example).

That's the essence of the difference between the two snippets.